# Issue in matching regexp in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I am having following pattern

```
Notif[0]:
some text multiple line
Notif[1]:
multiple line text
Notif[2]:
text again
Notif[3]:
text again
Finish
```

I am writting following regexp

```
set notifList [regexp -inline -all -nocase {Notif\[\d+\].*?(?=Notif|Finish)} $var]
```

It is not giving desired output

Output needed

```
I need a list with each `Notif`block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your `.*?` acts as a greedy subpattern (=`.*` matching 0+ any characters incl. a newline) because the first quantifier in the pattern was a greedy one (see `\d+`). See [this *Tcl Regex* reference](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.2.3/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72):

> A **branch has the same preference as the first quantified atom** in it which has a preference.

You need to just turn the first `+` quantified subpattern into a lazy one by adding a `?` after it:

```
Notif\[\d+?\].*?(?=Notif|Finish)
          ^
```

This will prevent the `.*?` pattern to inherit the greediness from the `\d+`.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/sRZgWC)

Comment: Yes, you can also use an unrolled *greedy* regex  pattern like [`Notif\[\d+\][^NF]*(?:(?:N(?!otif)|F(?!inish))[^NF]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/tM4pS8/1) but it is less readable. However, it is more efficient.

Comment: It need little more explanation. How `?` helped

Comment: All quantifiers in a branch get switched to the same greediness, and the first one encountered sets the greediness type: lazy or greedy. The `+` matches 1 or more characters as many as possible. Thus, the last `.*?` in your pattern matches all the text up to the last `Finish` or `Notif`. Adding a `?` to `+` makes `.*?` keep its lazy meaning, matching up to the first `Notif` or `Finish`.

Comment: Strictly, it's all quantifiers in the same finite automaton. Which is easy to understand on one level, but virtually impossible to correlate to the RE except at certain points (so `(?=…)` is one of the easy cases).